# Rails 4.1.6 Heroku Application Error on deployment

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've tried everything I can think of or Google. I can't understand why my Rails App won't deploy on Heroku.

I've switched from WebBrick to Unicorn server which works fine locally.
Also converted from SQLite3 to PostgrSQL. Run rake db:create / migrate. Destroyed and created a new Heroku repository.

Heroku accepts the push but when I try to deploy the app I keep getting this error message:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I've been stumped all day! I've read through the logs which show lots of problems (I guess) but I can't see a solution. Not really sure what to look for though...

Any clues would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

```
2014-10-11T12:44:13.004608+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by 
2014-10-11T12:44:13.004608+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by 
2014-10-11T16:45:10+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-10-11T16:46:00.915135+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by 
2014-10-11T16:46:01.352660+00:00 heroku[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by 
2014-10-11T16:46:01.352739+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by 
2014-10-11T16:46:01.484781+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL resource by 
2014-10-11T16:46:01.484841+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by 
2014-10-11T16:46:01.709332+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by 
2014-10-11T16:46:01.709249+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by 
2014-10-11T16:46:01+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-10-11T16:46:01.816634+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1b095c7 by 
2014-10-11T16:46:01.816710+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by 
2014-10-11T16:46:06.300267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829526+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:112:in `print_boot_information'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829515+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829492+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829523+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829528+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:64:in `start'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829525+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829532+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829533+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829535+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829537+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829538+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829540+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829541+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.852393+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829519+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829520+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2014-10-11T16:46:08.829517+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2014-10-11T16:46:09.693591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-10-11T16:46:09.703135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-10-11T16:46:09.703788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-10-11T16:46:12.622337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793857+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793818+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793839+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793843+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793841+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793844+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793846+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793850+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793854+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:112:in `print_boot_information'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793855+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:64:in `start'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793859+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793861+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793862+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793864+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793866+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.793867+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-10-11T16:46:14.813606+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-10-11T16:46:15.541599+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-10-11T16:46:15.535072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-10-11T16:46:17.156358+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-sierra-8698.herokuapp.com request_id=fc23f5aa-1ad0-4b97-8c59-d2560868bd92 fwd="54.161.120.115" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-10-11T16:46:29.378778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-sierra-8698.herokuapp.com request_id=8c0751d6-7ac7-4327-977e-0ca239efbbfe fwd="86.136.228.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-10-11T16:46:29.659854+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=guarded-sierra-8698.herokuapp.com request_id=86550a2e-c9ca-4470-b2ea-7d4cd4a9fd63 fwd="86.136.228.226" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem(s) solved. All 3 of them!

1. My Procfile was set to use the thin server instead of unicorn:

   +web: bundle exec rails server thin -c ./config/unicorn.rb

I misread a previous Stack Overflow post and set it to that.

2. The gem thin and it's 2 dependencies (gem eventmachine & gem daemons) were not in my .Gemfile or bundle, which caused a crash with this error message:

   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
3. Even all being well, Heroku doesn't display the rails default landing page. You have to specify a "Welcome" page in your routes, otherwise it throws up a 404 error.

**SOLUTIONS**

1. I installed and bundled the thin gem and its dependencies. This fixed the initial crash error above, but didn't solve my problem as I was still using the wrong server.
2. I corrected my Procfile to use the unicorn server:

   +web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
3. I set up a rails "Welcome" controller and routed to a very basic "Hello World" welcome page with a timestamp:

   ### Hello World

   The time is now:

All shows up perfectly on Heroku now!

Next I'll try removing the thin gem and dependencies. Hopefully they're a red herring and everything should still work fine. One step at a time though. I don't want to break it now it's up & working.

Hope this all helps somebody!